# I am trying to bulid this webpage with HTML and CSS but the layout is completely messed up dont know why

Tags: html, css

Below is the my complete code, the layout I am try is to get a navbar at the top with all the content in the center with a text box field and footer at the bottom

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8F8780;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #FF6600;
}
.navbar li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 20px;
}
.navbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  font-family: 'Bitter', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.jumbotron {
  clear: both;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #66CCFF;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.jumbotron input {
  border: solid 1px #E5E5E5;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.jumbotron input:hover,
input:focus {
  border-color: #C9C9C9;
}
#submit {
  border: 2px solid #33CC33;
  background: transparent;
  font-family: 'Actor', san-serif;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  color: #33CC33;
}
#submit:hover {
  background: #66FF66;
  color: white;
}
.footer {
  margin: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  border-top: 1px solid #8F8780;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #9A938D;
}
.footer a {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.footer p {
  font-family: 'Actor', san-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <form>
        <input type=text name="search" id="search" value="Enter the locality" />
        <input type="submit" id="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a> |
      <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
      <p>Copyright &copy 2015 Hotel Depot. All rights reserved</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

below is the link for jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/AzLQY/

Comment: Talk about a descriptive title

Comment: The HTML in the fiddle is not the same as in the question. Also, what does "messed up" mean?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that looks strange to me is the padding on jumbotron.
Try reducing the padding in '.jumbotron'